# Is there a permanent (non-emergency) patch/boot for a tire, NOT for a tube?

Tags: tire, repair

I have a discontinued tire with a tiny hole in the sidewall. I’d rather keep/use the tire if possible. I’m very familiar with emergency tire boots, but those are for emergencies. I’ve left them on slightly larger holes, and found they wear through, not necessarily just from abrasion of the road, but just from constant flex inherent with a tire. I’m looking for a more permanent patch for the inside of my tire, and NOT the tube. I searched and could not find anything.

The hole is in the fabric of the tire, and causes a slight bulge with an outside radius no larger than that of a pencil.

Is there such a product in existence?

Comment: Everyone knows there is nothing more perminant than a temporary repair that works, but no one will market them as anything more than a temporary repair because Lawyers won't let them.   Don't boot front tires ever, and the hassle and concern of checking a booted tire has me replacing it within a short time.

Comment: Thank you. Good answer.

Comment: Money! At least in the USA, a dollar bill will serve as a boot as long at the tire lasts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear from your answer if "tiny hole" means your tubeless sealant has a problem sealing it or that your inner tube is bulging through.

If the hole is really tiny, you can patch it with a tube patch. There are also dedicated tubeless tyre patches that are the same, but bigger and thicker. If the hole is really "tiny", they should work. If not, they could bulge through as well.

If the hole is bigger it can be sewn together. That can be then covered with a patch from the inside and with a polyurethane glue from the outside.

Only you can assess how dangerous that particular hole is and non-emergency such a repair can be. The higher pressures you use the worse it could be. Thin road tyres with 100 PSI and thick MTB tyres with 20 PSI are something completely different.